# How to display pdf file from Blob storage in asp.net C#,

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am trying to get files from Azure blob storage, I can connect and its can be downloaded, I need to view it in the application I have created, aspx page.

here is the code I used to download it, how can I display it on my page.
[here is the code I used to connect and download file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naxA1.png)

so I have a Grid view that have an Filename when a user click this file name in the grid its mist display the file.

my other problem, in my storage files are stored in different folders how to tell the code which folder and file.

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use google PDF viewer to display a PDF document on your page. Then I think you just need to  write a function to display the iframe-tag when a user clicks the file name

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview? url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true"
style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```